# How is とかいた being used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm continuing my quest to translate an episode of Terrace House for study purposes..

Naturally I have questions.. This question in particular is in regards to a phrase I got stuck on the tail-end of.

Japanese Subtitle:

> 印象に残ってるメンバー**とかいた**？

My Vocabulary Break-Down:

印象 - impression

残る - to remain, to be left

メンバー - house members

とかいた - ???

My literal translation attempt:

> your impression that you've been left with of the house members (???) was?

I'm trying to understand what とかいた is doing here...

Here are my best guesses...

- とか is being used on it's own like a conjunction "or/and", and いた is short form for いました. If this is the case how does this grammatically work? Something like "Your impression you were left with of the members **and it** was?" Not sure how とか would function in this scenario.
- と is being used as a particle "with the members", and then かいた is a
  past tense verb. (hard to determine what verb this would be without kanji).
- とかいた is some sort of completely different word on it's own that I'm unaware
  of yet.
- Or maybe this is a completely different grammar pattern I haven't learned yet.

Please help me understand this sentence.

Answer (score 6):

とか (and so on, etc.) and いた(existed, was) are correct in this scenario.

**Original**

> 印象に残ってるメンバーとかいた？

**Polite**

> あなたの印象に残っているメンバーなどは、いましたか？(polite)

**English**

> Did anyone leave an impression on you?

Students or young people use とか in conversations when they are seeking some topic to continue talking about, like:「見たい映画**とか**ある？」

They talk about not only movies. If I reply「あのアニメ見たい」 or 「映画館よりカフェに行こう」, we will change topics.

とか is often used in talking to extend the range of topics.

Comment: maybe adding your "version" of the translated sentece would be cool, I'm sure it could help OP understand the whole thing better imo.